# How to pass parameter to onInit method

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to add the parameter to GetxController's onInit method, and pass it whenever the controller init, how to achieve this code?

```
class TestModel extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit(String token) {
    fetchApi(token);
    super.onInit();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a variable and create a constructor for the controller then use it in the onInit?

Answer (score 2):

You can use constructor like this:

```
class TestModel extends GetxController{
 final String token;
 TestModel(this.token);

 @override
 void onInit() {
   fetchApi(token);
   super.onInit();
 }
 ...
}
```